# Docker network communication

Tags: docker, docker-compose, macvlan

I have a docker-compose project, let's say Users and Resources. I want containers in Users to connect to containers in Resource but, containers in Users should not communicate with each other. Each container in Users is an ssh server so I need to publish each ssh port to the host network to allow access from the Internet.

I have tried with macvlan but maybe there is some additional setup I have to do on the host iptables that I am not aware of.

How can I achieve this with docker/docker-compose ? Is there a better approach to the problem than using two docker-compose projects?

Comment: Create a docker network for each user container. Add resources to all the user networks. Update the resources networks every time you create/delete a user container. This will require a lot of logic on top of Docker. Logic you'd have to write yourself if you're up to it. Although, honestly, you're better off with Kubernetes and it's [Network Policies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/)

Answer (score 0):

Docker doesn't allow the setup you describe.  For two containers to connect to each other, they must be on the same network, so each of the "users" containers must be on the same network as the "resource" container.  But, if two containers are on the same network, they can communicate with each other.  So since all of the "users" containers need to be on the same network, they can all intrinsically communicate with each other.

One technically possible but hacky answer is to not use Docker networking but instead communicate via the host system.  Again, though, this won't solve your problem, since using this same technique any of the "users" containers could connect to another of the "users" containers' published ports.

More generally, it's hard to manage "a container per user", both operationally and for scaling purposes.  If you can set up a single externally accessible container that all of your users can use, it will only have a single published port, and the networking setup becomes much clearer.

Comment: In theory, it's possible to put two containers in two different networks in docker-compose.yml. Wouldn't it separate them entirely? Then put the third on both networks... Although it would get exponentially harder to maintain.

Comment: I guess in theory it's be possible to have a network per "users" container, and attach the "resources" container to all of them.  Again, though, this sort of setup quickly gets hard to maintain as you add users.  IME it's unusual to have a "hard" network partition between containers like you describe; Kubernetes, for example, has a single flat cluster-wide network and you need to go out of your way to prevent connections between containers.

Comment: I ended up using the approach of a single network per user where each network contains a replica of the resource + container with ssh. Each ssh container has a port mapping to the host. I thought this would have worked fine but, each user can see all the host-port mappings and can ping the gateway address of every other user. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: That sounds like you need to change your application code to not send ICMP echo packets (rarely useful in any case).  Maybe asking a separate question making sure to include your relevant application source code would be helpful.